# Appexchange product for Google Calendar / Contacts Sync

Tags: sales-cloud, google-apps

Looking for some apps that would help me to sync Google calendar and Contacts with Salesforce.

I am aware of the Cloud Sync from Appirio. Any other apps available for doing this?

Comment: We are using Cloud Sync, and some of our clients do as well, and we've heard nothing but good comments.

Answer (score 2):

Cirrus Insight is one of my favorites: http://www.cirrusinsight.com/
Contacts is available now, Calendar is coming soon.

Comment: As of this morning Cirrus Insight has released Calendar Sync: http://www.cirrusinsight.com/blog/sync-events-between-google-calendar-and-salesforce/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Ebsta (http://www.ebsta.com/), because with this free extension for Chrome, you could easily (without doing anything) synchronize Google Calendar with Salesforce Calendar.

For synchronizing Contacts, I recommend CloudWork.com (https://cloudwork.com/), but there is a one problem. They're not accepting new users at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HuEBEA0

CompanionLink - Sync with Android, iPhone, iPad, Google, and Outlook

CompanionLink is also an option